# OData 4.x Parser for .NET

Tags: c#, .net, odata

Is there an OData 4.x parser for .NET? I need to expose a proprietary data source via OData, so I can't just use EF's all-in-one option for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean you want to directly use OData Lib to do the parse?

Then you can use this class to do the uri parsing.

https://github.com/OData/odata.net/blob/ODataV4-6.x/src/Microsoft.OData.Core/UriParser/ODataUriParser.cs

Comment: Is it possible to use odata parser inside .net core app not in uri? for example i have a IQueryable data and i want to filter them inside my application and after filtering do som stuff on them